# which server to install for phpEclipse and how to do it?

Tags: php, compilation, server

I know this is a newbie question, but i want to study php. i have phpeclipse and its running well, the problem is when i run a simple html file with the default server the page says cant display this page and thats it. i dont know if i need to install a new server or is there something wrong with the server configurations. ive tried installing tomcat on my computer but i cant see it under windows->preferences->server->runtime enviroments->add. iv also tried under the same page to fetch geronimo v2.2 and 3.0 and the dependencies were wernt satisfied. iv also tried the repository for zend debugger. what do i need to do in order to compile and see php and html pages with php eclipse?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile PHP.

Depending on your operating system and PHP version there are a few options.

As of PHP 5.4+ you can run your application using PHP's built in server, on the command line, if you `cd` into your website root directory (i.e. where the index file is) and then run the following

```
php -S localhost:8989
```

Then if you navigate to http://localhost:8989 in your browser you should see your application.

If you are unable to run the inbuilt web server, you need to look at Apache2. Most PHP websites run inside the Apache 2 web server. You will generally need a *AMP (WAMP/LAMP) environment.

- L/W (Linux / Windows)
- A pache (Web server)
- M ySQL (Database)
- P HP

Hope this is enough of a pointer ;)